# Rspec HTML report with Fail Screenshot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, watir-webdriver

I kept my scripts in the below path:

```
C:\Desktop\RSpec_Folder
```

My code is:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'rautomation'
browser = Watir::Browser.new

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) { @browser = browser }
  config.after(:suite) { browser.close unless browser.nil? }
end  

describe "Outbid Home Scenarios validation" do  
  before(:each) do
    @browser.goto('http://www.outbid.com')
  end

  it "To validate outbid Logo/Home page navigation" do
    @browser.link(:id, "home-link").click
  end 

  it "Host & Join Live Auctions heading is available" do 
    @browser.text.include?('Host & Join Live Auctions')
  end

  it "Host & Join Live Auctions " do 
    @browser.text.include?('Host mail')
  end  

  after(:each) do
    @browser.close
  end  
end
```

My R spec file name is  `outbid.Rb`. While running the above scrips from command prompt with:

```
rspec --format html --out results.html outbid.rb
```

It is generating only HTML reports.

I want to create the report with screenshot for all passed and fail steps.

Comment: I don't see any ans...

Comment: How to use Selenium::RSpec::Reporting::HtmlReport in the above code to generate HTML report with Screenshot???

Comment: I did not see any references that the rspec html report had the ability to embed images. I have seen it for the Cucumber html report, but are you sure it exists in rspec?

Comment: Hi Justin please look into 'http://itreallymatters.net/post/318516310/the-beginning-of-watirs-rspec-html-formatter#.UZRsEHqdaZQ' url..

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed you were looking for built-in solution. Did Jarmo's solution/post solve your problem?

Comment: That blog posting was from 3 years ago, it makes me wonder if any of that ever got contributed back to rspec?   I did a bit of googling, but can't find much for that sort of thing with rspec.

Comment: No Justin... Actually i am not getting the solution..as i am new to RSpec

Answer (score 3):

You can use `watir-rspec` and its `Watir::RSpec::HtmlFormatter`, which automatically saves screenshots (and other files generated during the example) for all the failing specs.

Just follow the [README](https://github.com/watir/watir-rspec/blob/master/README.md) for the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you were hoping for, but it's realistic

Doing this with cucumber is easy.  There are multiple blog postings on the subject, and it takes but a few lines of code.

The thing is that Rspec is really designed around running UNIT tests, which almost never need to take or embed screenshots.  That sort of thing is much more common with acceptance tests, the sort of thing that Cucumber is designed for much more so than Rspec.

So your choice is to extend your framework (I'd start with the posting from Jarmo that you referenced in the comments to your question) or if that seems over your head and you don't want to take the time to learn the coding required for that, then consider your choice of frameworks, and look at something like Cucumber that is designed for acceptance tests and makes embedding screenshots in the HTML test results report a relative piece of cake.

**For cucumber**   In env.rb add code like this (note: this code only takes screenshots on failures, if you want them all the time then remove the if logic that is wrapped around the inner 4 lines of code)

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    screenshot = "./FAILED_#{scenario.name.gsub(' ','_').gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z_]/, '')}.png"
    @browser.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot)
    encoded_img = @browser.driver.screenshot_as(:base64)
    embed("data:image/png;base64,#{encoded_img}",'image/png')
  end
end
```

If rspec has a similar embed command, then you could likely put code very much like that inside of after(:each).  I've looked at the rdocs and find nothing like Embed, so I do not know if the stock Rspec framework can handle this.  (this may be more of a question for the rspec group)